Passport::actingAs($user) is giving a error on unit test
I upgrade my app from laravel 9 to laravel 11, ofcourse that includes the passport, now i have this simple test that has the following
    Passport::actingAs($this->user);

    $response = $this->get('/api/users');

    $response->assertStatus(200);

Which works okay before but now it is no but now it is getting this
NOT NULL constraint failed: oauth_access_tokens.id
I have migrated the passport migration
any help?
I have tried removing the Passport::routes on the AppServiceProvider as stated in the guide, my expectation is this test should pass without the error

Try this code instead
$this->actingAs($this->user);

Because it will automatically take your custom passport authentication endpoint
